# Ошибка при установке пакета Discord.Net.Commands в NuGet (visual studio 2019 c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, discord, nuget

При попытке установить пакет `Discord.Net.Commands` получаю следующую ошибку:

> Не удалось установить пакет «Discord.Net.Commands 2.2.0». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «native,Version=v0.0», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.

Comment: ну так а зачем пытаться установить пакет NET.Core в проект С++?

Comment: Исправил на discord.net.commands

Comment: @RAINGM Проект все-таки C++ или NET?

Comment: В проекте использую c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Версия платформы `native,Version=v0.0` означает, что у вас проект - обычное неуправляемое приложение С++. Но у пакета Discord.Net.Commands целевые платформы:

- .NETFramework4.6.1
- .NETStandard2.0
- .NETStandard2.1

То есть он совместим только с проектами .NET.

Comment: Но Discord.Net установилась без проблем.

Comment: @RAINGM Потому что этот пакет не содержит ни одной библиотеки, и видимо целевая платформа не проверяется. Если его открыть, то видно, что даже папки lib нет. Это псевдо-пакет, чтобы группой подключать другие пакеты.